# jScrollPane doesn't work when using it on a container of the scrollable element

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I've tried using jScrollPane on a `<div>` container of a `<ul>` element that I want to apply custom scrolling to.

When applying the plugin directly on the `<ul>` element, it works great, but jScrollPane injects HTML elements between the `<ul>` and its `<li>` child elements. 
I understand that this is not valid html, so I wanted to wrap the `<ul>` with a container and apply the plugin on the container.

This does not work , I don't understand fully why or how to test it. I've searched for similar problems with jScrollPane but didn't find any.

Thanks for your time...
Bar.

Comment: @user , i have implemented jscroll panel two years back at the following link http://www.art.com/gallery/id--b1823/animals-posters.htm?ui=35F9F675A32444BEB8036E09FDFF3FA6 , the parent container is div and inside you have all..UL block elements, let me know ifyou are tyring to achieve the same , we can fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem using jScrollPane on a dev with a UL inside it. This example does exactly that:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/vitch/g8CRL/1/

If you are still having problems please provide a URL (ideally to a test page created in jsfiddle but a page on your site will also work).